# uninitialized constant ActionController::IntegrationTest (NameError) when running cucumber tests

Tags: cucumber, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following configuration:

- Ruby 2.0.0-p247
- Rails 4.1.0.beta
- cucumber-1.3.5
- cucumber-rails-1.3.0

When I run either `rake cucumber` or `cucumber myfeature.feature`, I get

```
uninitialized constant ActionController::IntegrationTest (NameError)
/Users/lrains/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/cucumber-rails-1.3.0/lib/cucumber/rails/world.rb:9:in `<module:Rails>'
/Users/lrains/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/cucumber-rails-1.3.0/lib/cucumber/rails/world.rb:8:in `<module:Cucumber>'
/Users/lrains/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/cucumber-rails-1.3.0/lib/cucumber/rails/world.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/lrains/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/cucumber-rails-1.3.0/lib/cucumber/rails.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/lrains/balm/features/support/env.rb:7:in `require'
/Users/lrains/balm/features/support/env.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
...
```

Is this a compatibility issue?  How can I resolve it and run my tests?